# 0/1 - Knapsack and similar problem on 2D Matrix

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming

Problem: Given a 2d matrix of item **weights**, their respective **costs** in another 2d matrix, and **max capacity W**. Find the optimal selection such that profit is maximum(i.e sum of costs is maximum) and total items weight remains within capacity.

---

Now, Another constraint is you are **allowed to choose only a single item from each column** **[c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY2hv.jpg)**or choose no item from that column.

**This post has been answered,**
**Solution:**

```
        int Optimal(int available, int currIdx){

        if(currIdx>=n)
        return 0;

        if(DP[available][currIdx] !=-1)
        return DP[available][currIdx];

        if(currIdx == n-1)
        {
            int mx = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(available - c[i][currIdx]>=0) 
                mx = max(mx , w[i][currIdx]);
            }
        return mx;
        }


        int mx = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        int x = 0,y= 0;

        x = Optimal(available , currIdx +1);  //Don't include current
        if(available - c[i][currIdx] >=0)   
        {
            y = w[i][currIdx] +  Optimal(available - c[i][currIdx] , currIdx+1);// include current
        }

        mx = max( mx,max(x,y));    

        }

        return DP[available][currIdx] =  mx;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! You should show your work on the problem

Comment: Do you have problems in constructing the model or in solving it?

Comment: Both, like I am not able to think about how to model it, the standard knapsack is good but here I can only think of is, that we reoccur for next column from every element of a single column and decide whether we should include or not, and move further, memoize where ever possible.

Comment: [*generalized assignment problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem)

Comment: The *problem* and *a solution* are clear, but the *question* is not.

Comment: as metamorphy is saying you should show what is your question: I think you last comment on this section would fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the modelling**

Define : $$x_{ij}= \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } \mbox{ element at position $ij$ in the matrix is selected} \\ 0 &  \mbox{otherwise } \end{cases}$$

So you want to find :

$$\max \:\: \sum_{i=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^M{c_{ij}x_{ij}}$$

subject to :
$$\sum_{i=0}^N{x_{ij}} \leq 1  \:\: \forall j$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^M{w_{ij}x_{ij}} \leq W$$

**For the algorithm**

If you want an easier approach than simplex algorithm try with a simple backtracking algorithm, in which you compare current combination cost with current maximum and you get back in recursion when you arrive at $W' \geq W$; it's better than comparing every combination

Comment: Yes, this looks good.

Comment: if you want an easier approach I updated

Comment: see I have added code to my question, is it the way to go?

Comment: I know just Python, I'm not able to read the code ahah, but it seems to me that you applied all the conditions, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does  work.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to model a knapsack problem is that you got $N$ items with weights $w_{ij}$ and costs $c_{ij}$ then to maximize profit given a capacity constraint by choosing only a single item from each column, you should solve the following binary linear program
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maximize}}
& & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=1}^N c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=1}^N w_{ij}x_{ij} \leq W \\
& & & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \leq 1  \quad \forall j = 1 \ldots M \\
& & & x_{ij} \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
A common relaxation here is to drop the binary constraint and solve the linear program
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maximize}}
& & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=1}^N c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=1}^N w_{ij}x_{ij} \leq W \\
& & & \sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \leq 1  \quad \forall j = 1 \ldots M 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
You can use methods such as [Simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) or the dual simplex and so on.

Comment: I think you missed this "Now, Another constraint is you are allowed to choose only a single item from each column or choose no item from that column." it's highlighted now.

Comment: @PratyushTiwari recheck

Comment: Yes, I got what you wrote, but I didn't know about the Simplex Algorithm, but I checked and read a little and it's not very clear how to implement it, can you spend a little more time explaining in programming terms.

Comment: @PratyushTiwari that would be another question. On the other hand, I have left a wikipedia link that details how the algorithm works. 
Also here is a youtube video https://youtu.be/dAyeNmz6p-c

Comment: Your answer is helpful, and your channel also has great content @machine learning.